# Cannot create Sql Server database in App_Data folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-express

When I try to create an Sql Server Database in the App_Data folder of my Visual Studio 2010 project, I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user:[Domain]\[user]
```

I am able to create databases using Sql Server Management Studio. I am using Sql Server Express 2008.

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using express edition, in Visual Studio go to Tools>Options>Database Tools>Data Connections.

Remove the SQL Server Instance Name and click OK.

Now try connection to the server using Server Explorer. Once you get connected, you will be able to create a new DB in App_Data folder.

Here is the connection string:

```
public string ConStr = "Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|CodeDB.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Also make sure that you have `user instances` for your DB enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013:

Go to Tools-->> Options-->>Database Tools-->>Data Connections. SQL Server Instance Name

Type ProjectsV12

Then Create SQL Server Database inside the App_Folder, and it will work.

Open CommandPrompt as administrator

Type `sqllocaldb info` and press enter

It will display all the available local db.